# Google deprecates their AJAX crawling scheme

Tags: ajax, indexing, seo, google-index

As announced yesterday (14 October 2015) on their blog http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.bg/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html, they are deprecating their AJAX crawling scheme.

From the blog post it's not clear for me if we should completely leave AJAX loaded content if we want this content to be indexed or we just have to stop serving content when `_escaped_fragment_` is present in the url and do serve content with the original `#!` as Google would no longer replace a `#!` fragment with `_escaped_fragment_=`?

For example if up to now we're loading our Google index friendly page like this:

`example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=page=contacts`

From now on we should serve the content like this:

`example.com/#!page=contacts`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: @JohnConde do you think it's off-topic, as almost every Single Page App these days serves their content using AJAX and if they want their content to be indexed, they MUST consider Google AJAX crawling rules. Just as a matter of fact I'm pure developer and I tend to not care about SEO at all, but as a creator of an app - I'm responsible if its content can't be indexed.